# getting information from Entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

my name is Rod. I recently started programming with OOP and it's not yet quite clear to me. I want to make my Button get information from my four entries but i don't know how to say to the program to get it from the four of them at the same time. I know i have to use the get() method but i don't understand how to insert it in the class so it will recognize my four Entries. Thanks!

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Application(Frame):
     def __init__(self):
         Frame.__init__(self)
         self.grid()

     def createButton(self,b_text,b_command,r,c):
         self.newButton = Button(self, text=b_text,command=b_command)
         self.newButton.grid(padx=20, pady=10, row=r,column=c)

     def createEntry(self,px,r,c):
          text = StringVar()
          self.newEntry = Entry(self,width=8,textvariable=text)
          self.newEntry.grid(padx=px, pady=10,row=r,column=c)

def printEntryData():
    #code here

app = Application()

entry1 = app.createEntry(20,0,0)
entry2 = app.createEntry(20,0,1)
entry3 = app.createEntry(20,0,2)
entry4 = app.createEntry(20,0,3)

app.createButton("add",printEntryData,1,6)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: `print(entry1.get(), entry2.get(), ...)`

Comment: @BryanOakley that would only work if you add `return text` to the "createEntry" method.

Comment: @Novel: ah, yes. Good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you make an entry you overwrite the previous value of `text`. All those previous Entry boxes now are orphans: there's no way to access them to get the information out. (they would have been inaccessible anyway since they are local variables).

Instead, you could add the new StringVars to a container like a list, so that you have access to all of them.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Application(Frame):
     def __init__(self):
         Frame.__init__(self)
         self.entry_list = []
         self.grid()

     def createButton(self,b_text,b_command,r,c):
         self.newButton = Button(self, text=b_text,command=b_command)
         self.newButton.grid(padx=20, pady=10, row=r,column=c)

     def createEntry(self,px,r,c):
          text = StringVar()
          self.newEntry = Entry(self,width=8,textvariable=text)
          self.newEntry.grid(padx=px, pady=10,row=r,column=c)
          self.entry_list.append(text)

def printEntryData():
    for entry in app.entry_list:
        print(entry.get())

app = Application()

app.createEntry(20,0,0)
app.createEntry(20,0,1)
app.createEntry(20,0,2)
app.createEntry(20,0,3)

app.createButton("add",printEntryData,1,6)

app.mainloop()
```